# Expo build process allows wrongly typed TypeScript to build successfully. How to make it fail for every rebuild?

Tags: typescript, expo

The context is Expo (React Native) with TypeScript.
When you connect your phone, and your "reload" the app, then Expo rebuilds it. You will see in the code below that `App.tsx` has a wrongly typed call: `myFunc('xxxx')`, but Expo builds it anyway successfully. How can I make that build fail?

The common way is to run the TypeScript check manually, however I want it to run automatically every time expo before Expo rebuilds the app when the phone "reloads" while the Expo server is running.

My current setup is below (for convenience, [here is the replit](https://replit.com/@dev235/projname#app.json) but it won't run in replit)

```
# App.tsx
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App()
{
  function myFunc(param:'foo'|'bar') {}

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Button title="click it" onPress={()=>{
          myFunc('xxxx');
      }}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
# package.json
{
  "name": "la8app5",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~50.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
# tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

```
# babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

```
# app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "la8app5",
    "slug": "la8app5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Googling suggested installing eslint for expo https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-eslint/ , but that didn't do the trick.
`npm install eslint prettier eslint-config-universe --save-dev`
That would need this extra config file:

```
#.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'universe/native',
  ],
};
```

And installing eslint would add this to `package.json`

```
# edit package.json
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ."
}
```

Comment: _"[installing ESLint] didn't do the trick"_ - you have to `npm run lint` to [use ESLint](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-eslint/), as you have to `npm run ts:check` to [use TypeScript](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/). It's not part of what Expo itself (or Babel, which it uses) does - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8273